# Custom Fonts Not Working

Tags: xcode, fonts

I'm trying to give a label a custom font.
I've added the fonts to my project file and copied them to my project.

[image]

I've also added them to my info.plist file

[image]

This is the font in fontbook:

[image]

In my viewDidLoad method I'm using the following code:

```
_museoFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo" size:14];
_lblPlayer1Score.font = _museoFont;
```

Comment: Debug time: `NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont familyNames]);` and `NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:"family name you found in first NSLog"]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postscript name of e.g. Museo 300 is `@"Museo-300"`. The hyphen is crucial. In any case the name you are using ("Museo") is meaningless; it doesn't specify *any* of the fonts in question, and if it did, it would be ambiguous.

The following code will always tell you (in the console) all the correct names of all the fonts you have:

```
for (NSString* s in [UIFont familyNames])
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", s, [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:s]);
```

Comment: Awesome code. However, I ran that code and don't see Museo mentioned any where. Amy I missing something else? Have I included it into the project incorrectly?

Comment: Also I changed the code:
_museoFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo-300" size:14];
    _lblPlayer1Score.font = _museoFont;

Comment: I got it! You have to make sure that the "Target Membership" is checked for each font in the file inspector menu.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you've provided, there are no fonts named "Museo". From the [UIFont Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_18):

> *fontName*
>   The fully specified name of the font. This name incorporates both the font family name and the specific style information for the font.

Try `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo 300" size:14];`

Answer (score 0):

Open the font with *Font Book.app*
Select the font, do *Cmd+I*, and if I remember correctly, you should use the "*PostScript Name*" as the font name for `fontWithName:`.